MudBlazor Dialog won't show after updating to .NET8/MudBlazor7 on Blazor WASM
I've been building a Blazor WebAssembly (WASM) app since DOTNET 6 (note: I do not have a Server Side head in this app), and after the most recent update, I can no longer get dialogs to show. All of this code used to work, and no changes have been made other than to accommodate the breaking changes for MudBlazor 7.
In my MainLayout.razor, I have the following.
<MudThemeProvider IsDarkMode="@_isDarkMode" Theme="_theme"/>
<MudPopoverProvider/>
<MudDialogProvider/>
<MudSnackbarProvider/>

And then in my ViewModel
public sealed class EditProductViewModel
{
    public EditProductViewModel(IDialogService dialogService)
    {
        _dialogService = dialogService.ThrowIfNull();

        // sets up the public API surface to use an Rx Interaction layer
        _getThingInteraction.RegisterHandler(GetThingFromDialog);
    }

    public async Task AddThing(ProductFormat productFormat)
    {
        using var _ = _logger.AutoLogInOut();
        var result = await _getThingInteraction.Handle(Unit.Default);
        if (result != null)
        {
            productFormat.ThingDetails.AddThing(result);
            StateChanged();
        }
    }

    private async Task GetThingFromDialog(IInteractionContext<Unit, Thing> context)
    {
        using var _ = _logger.LogTraceInOut();
        var parameters = new DialogParameters
            {
                [nameof(SelectThingDialog.Things)] = ThingDropDown
            };
        var dialog = await _dialogService.ShowAsync<SelectThingDialog>("Select a thing", parameters);
        var result = await dialog.Result;
        context.SetOutput(!result?.Canceled ?? false
            ? result.Data as Thing
            : null);
    }

    private readonly IDialogService _dialogService;
    private readonly Interaction<Unit, Thing> _getThingInteraction = new();
}

Then my page has a simple button
        <MudButton Class="pull-right"
                   Color="Color.Info"
                   Variant="Variant.Filled"
                   StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Add"
                   OnClick="() => BindingContext.AddThing(productFormat)">
            Add Thing
        </MudButton>

When I click the button, I can see the logging whereby the interaction is getting called (IN), but the dialog never shows.

[ VRB ][ wrkr : 1 ]    myApp.Portal.Pages.Features.Products.EditProductViewModel : >>  GetThingFromDialog

I have tried changing the RenderMode but that doesn't seem to accomplish what I need since Interactive Service isn't supported on WASM.
What do I need to do to get dialogs working again?
Edit
I've updated the MainLayout.razor to specify InteractiveWebAssembly specifically, and still I get the same result.
<MudThemeProvider IsDarkMode="@_isDarkMode" Theme="_theme"  @rendermode="RenderMode.InteractiveWebAssembly"/>
<MudPopoverProvider @rendermode="RenderMode.InteractiveWebAssembly"/>
<MudDialogProvider  @rendermode="RenderMode.InteractiveWebAssembly"/>
<MudSnackbarProvider  @rendermode="RenderMode.InteractiveWebAssembly"/>


Can you reproduce here? https://try.mudblazor.com/

@mxmissile I don't think I can because I issue seems to be specific to WASM and the playground renders server side

So you are sure the code works server side?

"what I need since Interactive Service isn't supported on WASM." You're supposed to use  InteractiveWebAssembly for WASM. If none of your code has changed and you don't have interactivity then it's most definitely a @rendermode issue.

@mxmissile I have never had a server-side component for this app, it has always been exclusively WASM. What I meant to say before is that the code used to work as expected before I updated to MudBlazor7 and DotNet8.

@RBee I also tried defining that explicitly (see most recent edit), yet I still don't see the dialogs. As I said in a previous comment, my code used to work as expected before the update to MudBlazor7 and DotNet8.

You can compare with their templates, https://github.com/mudblazor/Templates , all MudBlazor components need interactivity and since you're only WASM then setting the rendermode globally should be the way.

Set Interactivity to global i.e. on the components in App.Razor.  Do you have a use case for choosing Per Page/Component?  Setting it on the providers is plain wrong.

Where is MudButtonEx coming from? Please post a reproducible example. This is why I asked about try.mudblazor.com.
